# Why is the top border of this inline element not displaying and why does using float correct this?

Tags: css

http://jsbin.com/ofojis/edit#preview

http://jsbin.com/ofojis/edit#source

1. Why is the top border of this inline element not displaying?
2. Adding `float:left` pushes this inline element down and it renders
   well.  How does `float:left` actually push it down, isn't it
   supposed to push an element to the left?
3. Also, are you not supposed to use the margin property on inline
   elements like `<span>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Technical explanation of how outline, border and padding are rendered in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193395/technical-explanation-of-how-outline-border-and-padding-are-rendered-in-this-ex/) ? :)

1. Because `<span>` is an `inline` element, and the positioning of `inline` elements starts from the top-left of the padding (not counting the border and margin).
2. `float: left` applies `display: inline-block`, which means that it's no longer `inline`. The positioning for `inline-block` elements starts from the top-left of the margin.
3. You can use `margin` on a `<span>` but it won't do anything useful :P

Comment: I'm a slow learner lol.  Thanks for your answer.  Your #2 was particularly enlightening.  I was confused because margins seemed to work when I applied `float:left` to `<span>` but it all makes sense now =).  Can you recommend any guides written in layman terms for me?  w3schools doesn't go over the finer details the way you did.

Comment: Lol, fair enough. It's certainly not obvious that `float` applies `inline-block`, took me some time to realise that myself. I don't know of any guides that go into that kind of depth, you just learn it as you get older :P

Comment: Also Joe, for your #1, do block elements start from the top left (counting padding and margin)?

Comment: Yep - inline ignores border and margin for its positioning. Inline-block and block take everything into account.

Comment: @Joe in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308944/cant-see-the-border-top-in-this-inline-element) I can see inline element doesn't ignore the border-left, just the border-top. Or maybe I'm wrong.